# One single output file for many regressions

Tags: r, stargazer

Is there a way to write text output from stargazer to one single file from several regressions? As far as I see, I can specify the `out=` parameter at each single regression but how to tell stargazer to use one single text file?

Comment: Do you mean something different than passing multiple model objects to be displayed in a single table?

Comment: Yes, multiple models' tables to be saved to one single text file. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I'm just trying to clarify, because `stargazer()` will by default accept multiple model objects. There are numerous examples in the docs and the vignette. So I thought maybe you meant something different...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you grab the output from `stargazer` you can do what you like with it:

```
for(m in models){
  s = capture.output(stargazer(m))
  cat(paste(s,"\n"),file="foo",append=TRUE)
  cat("and another one....\n",file="foo",append=TRUE)
}
```

Maddeningly, `stargazer` prints the table even when you do `out="/dev/null"`, otherwise you could do this without lots of output with:

```
for(m in models){
  s = stargazer(m)
  cat(paste(s,"\n"),file="foo",append=TRUE)
  cat("and another one....\n",file="foo",append=TRUE)
}
```

because `stargazer` returns the string it just printed (and optionally output to the file too).